# NSMutableArray allocated memory in tableview cellFoRowAtIndexPath delegate and it is leaking memory even after release

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

```
NSMutableArray *lCellColValues =(NSMutableArray *)nil;
lCellColValues = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
if(0 == lSecModulus) //trans info cell
   {

      if cObjTransListPtr.count >0 && lObjTransData.m_cObjSDElemInfoPtr.count > 0 ) 
        {

           [lCellColValues addObject:lObjTransData.m_cObjTransNamePtr];
           [lCellColValues addObject:[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:lObjTransData.m_cTransCounter] stringValue]];

        }else {  

             if (nil != lObjSDElemInfo.m_cObjStartTimePtr) 
                {

                   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                   dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
                   [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
                   NSString *myDateAsString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:lObjSDElemInfo.m_cObjEndTimePtr];
                   [lCellColValues addObject:myDateAsString];
                   SAFE_RELEASE(dateFormatter)

                }else{

                     [lCellColValues addObject:@""];

                }           
           [lCellColValues addObject:[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lObjSDElemInfo.m_cElementTime] stringValue]];
         }
   }
if((CustSplitCell *)nil == lObjCellPtr){

     if (m_cObjTransListPtr.count > 0) {

              lObjCellPtr = [[[CustSplitCell alloc]initWithStyleAndTitles:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:lObjCellIdentifier titles:lCellColValues rowNumber:indexPath.row] autorelease];

        }else { 
             [lCellColValues addObject:@""];
             lObjCellPtr = [[[CustSplitCell alloc]initWithStyleAndTitles:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:lObjCellIdentifier titles:lCellColValues rowNumber:indexPath.row] autorelease];
        }
  }
```

In this code **lCellColValues** is leaking memory even if we autorelease it. Any idea why it is showing leak??

Comment: `NSMutableArray *lCellColValues =(NSMutableArray *)nil;` It gave me cancer. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *lCellColValues =[NSMutableArray array];
```

it will automatically allocated and release.

Comment: If i give NSMutableArray *lCellColValues =[NSMutableArray array]; addObject statement is showing memory leak and I am calling customclass and initialising that class data by using this array.Now it is shown as potential memory leak

Comment: No it is not fixing the memory leak.I need a solution please i will accept any solution suggest me.